# How to find the root cause for some Access Denied error on a windows machine?

Tags: security, permissions, privileges

I was wondering if there is a way to discover the exact reasons for an Access Denied error on a windows box.

For instance, I have this code that crashes with Access Denied on Win2008R2 when it runs unelevated. I was hoping that ProcMon will tell me exactly which resource denied access - it did not, although I did not filter the events.

So, I am a bit lost - how on earth am I supposed to troubleshoot it?

For the reference, the code I am trying to run is `ICertAdmin2.ResubmitRequest`. It runs OK elevated, but fails with Access Denied when ran unelevated:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: CCertAdmin::ResubmitRequest: Access is denied. 0x80070005 (WIN32: 5)
   at CERTADMINLib.ICertAdmin2.ResubmitRequest(String strConfig, Int32 RequestId)
```

Thanks in advance to all the Good Samaritans out there.

Answer (score 0):

ProcMon wont, but filemon probably would. It tells you the success/denies and the searches.

Chances are its trying to write to program files (but not limited to that) but filemon will tell you

Comment: ProcMon supersedes both FileMon and RegMon. In fact, the SysinternalsSuite does not contain neither of the latter.

Comment: No, but the old filemon was very good at quickly honing in these things, I still have the old one.

Comment: I do not have any reasons to believe that ProcMon falls short of FileMon. I used to use FileMon and now  I use ProcMon and I never saw any advantage of the former over the latter. In any case, FileMon is no longer supported by Sysinternals.

Comment: Sysinternals sadly got bought by MS. OK, but if you're failing to be able to locate the failing file(s) this would be difficult to work out as previously thats how Ive always found my failing files and not had any that escaped this.

Comment: The thing, is that it is probably not a file object after all. This is why ProcMon does not see it. (and not because it is inferior to FileMon, which it is not).

Answer (score 0):

The error code you're getting looks like a COM HRESULT error code.  All these have a specific meaning.  Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb401631.aspx) to find out more how to interpret them.

Comment: I do not need this site. The file WinError.h from Microsoft Windows SDK contains this stuff: //
// General access denied error
//
#define E_ACCESSDENIED                   _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80070005L)

Comment: is this a network access denied or just on the local machine?

Comment: This is local machine. Both the CA and my utility run on the same machine. No shared folders involved.